WSL container terminates immediately once the last console is closed
I'm running WSL2 on Windows 10 22H2 (10.0.19045.4412).
After a recent WSL update I noticed a change in its behaviour: whenever the last console session (i.e. a running wsl.exe process) is closed, the entire container is stopped after a short grace period. I can clearly see this by running
for /l %n in () do cls & wsl -l --running & timeout /t 1

Previously, I could start wsl.exe, execute sudo service ssh start, log out of the console session, and then connect via SSH whenever I needed, all my processes running in the background.
Now, to preserve the same workflow, I have to always keep at least one console session (a running wsl.exe) open.
Interestingly, I also have Docker installed which is backed by WSL. Docker installs two "synthetic" Linux distributions, named docker-desktop and docker-desktop-data. These two WSL containers are unaffected by the update, i.e. they continue running in the background despite there's no "console" session.
wsl --version outputs:
WSL version: 2.2.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.61
MSRDC version: 1.2.5326
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.26091.1-240325-1447.ge-release
Windows version: 10.0.19045.4412

How do I revert to the old behaviour (e.g. by editing ~/.wslconfig and/or /etc/wsl.conf)?

whenever the last console session ... is closed, the entire container is stopped after a short grace period. - WSL has always behaved this way for me. Maybe something in here will help
